# Error when reading AppManifest.xaml file in silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0

I am new to silverlight. In my application I have to load different XAP files dynamically.

I am getting the below error when reading AppManifest.xaml file .

The method or operation is not implemented.

Here is my code.

Private Sub Button_Click_2(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs)

```
    Dim wc As New WebClient() 

    AddHandler wc.OpenReadCompleted, AddressOf EndOpenReadCompleted2

    wc.OpenReadAsync(New Uri("WebPortalUI.xap", UriKind.Relative))



End Sub



Private Sub EndOpenReadCompleted2(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As OpenReadCompletedEventArgs) 



    Dim appManifest As String = New StreamReader(Application.GetResourceStream(New StreamResourceInfo(e.Result, Nothing), New Uri("AppManifest.xaml", UriKind.Relative)).Stream).ReadToEnd()

    'Dim deploy As Deployment = TryCast(XamlReader.Load(appManifest), Deployment)

    Dim deploy As XElement = XDocument.Parse(appManifest).Root  //Here Error is coming





    Dim asm As System.Reflection.Assembly = Nothing



    For Each asmpart As AssemblyPart In deploy.Parts

        Dim source As String = asmpart.Source

        Dim streamInfo As StreamResourceInfo = Application.GetResourceStream(New StreamResourceInfo(e.Result, "application/binary"), New Uri(source, UriKind.Relative))

        asm = asmpart.Load(streamInfo.Stream)

    Next



    Dim type As Type = asm.GetType("WebPortalUI.Reports")   // Reports.xaml is one page
```

How can I solve this problem?

Regards,

JN